# React Router Not Working Correctly with Manual URL Entry

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router-dom, webpack-dev-server

I have a simple React Route set up with Nested Routes using `react-router-dom`

```
<Link to={"/"} replace={false}>Home</Link>
<Link to={"/routeA/pageA"} replace={false}>Page A</Link>
<Link to={"/routeB/pageB"} replace={false}>Page B</Link>

<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<p>Home</p>} />
    <Route path="/routeA">
        <Route index element={<p>Not Found</p>} />
        <Route path="pageA" element={<p>Page A</p>} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/routeB">
        <Route index element={<p>Not Found</p>} />
        <Route path="pageB" element={<p>Page B</p>} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" element={<p>Not Found</p>} />
</Routes>
```

That is being run with the webpack dev server and these settings

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  devServer: {
    port: "31",
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, "public")
    },
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    liveReload: true,
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  ...
};
```

The routes seem to be working fine when being accessed with the links and using the browser "Back" button it seems to be working fine as well, but when trying to use the URLs in the search bar manually it doesn't seem to work right.

When only using the top level Routes it seems to work fine

```
http://siteurl:31/ : shows Home (correct)
http://siteurl:31/routeA : shows Not Found (correct)
http://siteurl:31/routeB : shows Not Found (correct)
```

But when trying to use the nested Routes

```
http://siteurl:31/routeA/pageA : crashes
http://siteurl:31/routeA/anything : crashes
http://siteurl:31/routeB/pageB : crashes
http://siteurl:31/routeB/anything : crashes
```

With the error

```
GET http://siteurl:31/setup/index_bundle.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Full code:

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "Example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Example",
  "main": "./index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server .",
    "bundle": "webpack ."
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "none"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "none"
  ],
  "author": "Dev User",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.22.15",
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.15",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.15",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.15",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    filename: "index_bundle.js"
  },
  target: "web",
  devServer: {
    port: "31",
    static: { directory: path.join(__dirname, "public") },
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    liveReload: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    allowedHosts: "all"
  },
  resolve: { extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json"] },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: { presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"] }
        }
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [ new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html") }) ]
};
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import {createRoot} from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./src/App.js";

const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<App/>);
```

public/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

src/App.js

```
import React from "react";
import {BrowserRouter, Link, Routes, Route, Outlet} from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Link to={"/"} replace={false}>Home</Link>
            <Link to={"/routeA/pageA"} replace={false}>Page A</Link>
            <Link to={"/routeB/pageB"} replace={false}>Page B</Link>

            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<p>Home</p>} />
                <Route path="/routeA">
                    <Route index element={<p>Not Found</p>} />
                    <Route path="pageA" element={<p>Page A</p>} />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/routeB">
                    <Route index element={<p>Not Found</p>} />
                    <Route path="pageB" element={<p>Page B</p>} />
                </Route>
                <Route path="*" element={<p>Not Found</p>} />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: How are you building, and serving/hosting, this React app? Can you [edit] to clarify? See [mcve]. The basic gist is that the root index.html file should be returned for all page requests into application. Can you share also your index.html and index.js files, and any other files you think may be relevant?

Comment: @DrewReese I've created as small of a reproducible example as I can and updated the question